# How to calculate a capacitor's discharge time?

Tags: capacitor, discharge, electrolytic-capacitor, capacitor-charging

How do i calculate a capacitor with a specific capacitance loaded with a specific resistance discharge time and reach a specific voltage?

So let's say i have a 22uF capacitor charged with 12 volts and loaded with a 500 ohm load, how many seconds does it take to reach the capacitor's voltage of 6 volts?

Comment: If you would like help with a homework question, you need to show work first. What have you tried? What formulas are available to do this?

Comment: This is a simple "transient RC" problem. Have you done any investigating yourself about such circuits?

Comment: A google search for "capacitor discharge equation" returns this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capdis.html

Comment: @vini_i I'm not dealing with a homework, i'm an amateur hobbyist and i haven't tried any formula because i don't know what formula should i use

Comment: @vangelo Sorry, i can't understand that because i'm not experienced with the math

Comment: Your question is **very** basic is covered on numerous websites. Please search internet on the title of this question, try understand it. If you have questions, show your equations and tell where you are stuck. We're happy to help from there

Comment: I'm sorry but the math on the wikipedia page is as simple as it gets. You might need to improve your math skills before you try to tackle these engineering problems.